# Do `docker container rm` and `docker container kill` effectively achieve the same?

Tags: docker

From manpages:

> `docker container rm` will remove one or more containers from the host
>   node. The container name or ID can be used. This does not remove
>   images.
>
> `docker container kill`: The main process inside each container
>   specified will be sent SIGKILL,  or any signal specified with option
>   --signal.

Is a container a running instance of an image?
So do  `docker container rm` and `docker container kill` effectively achieve the same: the container will stop existing?

What are their differences?

What is "the main process inside a container"?

Is a container   run exactly as a process in the host machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run a container..

eg

```
docker run alpine echo hello
```

It looks like it cleans up afterwards...

```
% docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

But it doesn't it's still there.

```
% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
3a4772c0f165        alpine              "echo hello"        22 seconds ago      Exited (0) 20 seconds ago                       relaxed_ramanujan
```

This can be cleaned up with the `rm` command

```
% docker container rm 3a4772c0f165 
3a4772c0f165

% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

So:

- `docker kill` will kill a container.
- `docker rm` will clean up a terminated container.

They are different things.

Note: you can tell containers to auto-clean:

```
% docker run --rm alpine echo hello
hello

% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Then you don't need to manually `rm`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what does it mean that docker "cleans"?
What do really happens when a container is "uncleaned" and shows up with the "Exited 0" status?

Answer (score 7):

A container is (at least):

- running processes
- a top ephemeral layer, to its file-system.
- volume and network mappings.

Kill will only deal with the first one.

If you run with `--rm` option. Then stopping, or killing the container, will also remove it.

You should not use kill (unless you have to), `docker stop` sends SIGTERM. (If you have to send SIGKILL to a process, this it is badly behaved, and need fixing.)